# Ubuntu slows down after running heavy computation

Tags: intel, cpu, fan

My PC's CPUs stop performing well after heavy computation (using python) for a few hours. Everything operates slowly. The fan stops and CPU temperatures are around 45 degrees C, but the CPU utilization is displayed at close to 100 percent according to the system monitor. The system monitor also indicates that RAM utilization is very low.

A restart fixes the issue but I need to be able to run computations for an extended period. I have a Dell xps 15 laptop with an Intel Core i7 7700HQ/2.8GHz and 32 GB RAM (DDR4 SDRAM with 2400 MHz) and I am running Ubuntu 16.04. I don't experience the same issue on my Windows 10 boot.

Here is output from the kernel logger where a lot of logging occurs at 22:21:52:

[Kernel output logger](https://pastebin.com/2dZrFM7Q)

[System Monitor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWu8g.png)

Comment: I think that it would be more useful to paste the computation script instead of CPU info. Maybe is the script "bad" resource management or something that causes slow-down after hours of use.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I am not sure what you mean by computation script. Is it the load and processes that are running over time or perhaps the kernel output? I added the kernel output in the original question.